# Can't see online contacts on Miranda IM

Tags: miranda-im

A friend of mine has a weird problem with Miranda IM.. She has just one ICQ account, but when she goes online she can't see whether her contacts are online too.. They just remain grey/offline. On the other hand, people *can* see her online, and they can chat too.. Any idea on what the problem could be? :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to ask for authentication in order to see other contacts online. This change dates back at least a few months. Came as a surprise to me as I usually didn't care about that and it worked anyway.

Recently ICQ seems to have changed something else which causes the described behavior. For me logging on to ICQ2Go, deleting the contact and re-adding it worked and I was able to see them online in Miranda again.

Comment: I'll tell to try this ASAP, thanks :) (Didn't think authentication could have been "revoked" in some way)

Comment: The current issue doesn't seem to be auth, though. Or maybe it is and Miranda just does some things wrong. Or ICQ changed the protocol.

Comment: Did you re-add the contact from Miranda or from ICQ2go?

Comment: I deleted and re-added from ICQ2Go.